# Solution to ODE in terms of eigenfunctions of differential operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, eigenfunctions

Can anyone please recommend a textbook or publication, where the theory of linear ordinary differential equations is explained from operator-theoretical perspective? That is, solutions to the ODEs are derived in terms of eigenfunctions of differential operators?

Comment: ‘Sturm-Liouville Problems: Theory and Numerical Implementation,’ Guenther and Lee, is good.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How about Cauchy/initial value problems? Are they covered in that book as well?

Comment: no, strictly the Sturm-Liouville theory.